# How to round Informix datetime by half hour, quarter and hour?

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

This is so easy to do in SQL Server and Informix is making me angry.
Showing the hour a datetime is in is easy:

```
select startdatetime,
startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR AS IntervalHour
from Contactcalldetail ccd
```

Gives:

> ```
> startdatetime     IntervalHour
> 04-05-2016 19:53:35   19
> ```

I want:

> ```
> startdatetime     IntervalHour    IntervalHalfHour    IntervalQuarterHour
> 04-05-2016 19:53:35   19              19:30               19:45
> 04-05-2016 19:56:57   19              19:30               19:45
> 04-05-2016 20:23:14   20              20:00               20:15
> ```

So far I've tried....cursing at my screen, telling google to go to horrible places because it gives me results not including the word "informix".

Thoughts on what else to try?

Comment: You're not rounding. You're flooring/truncating. Eg rounding 20:23 to the quarter hour would give 20:30, not 20:15. Please clarify.

Comment: good point, I think flooring would be the better term. I want to go down to the nearest interval

Answer (score 0):

may be it will help you.

```
select startdatetime
      , startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR AS IntervalHour
      , Case when DatePart(minute,startdatetime)>=30 then cast(DatePart(hour,startdatetime) as varchar)+':30'
        else cast(DatePart(hour,startdatetime) as varchar)+':00'
        End
        as IntervalHalfHour
      , Case when DatePart(minute,startdatetime)>=45 then cast(DatePart(hour,startdatetime) as varchar)+':45'
        when DatePart(minute,startdatetime)>=15 then cast(DatePart(hour,startdatetime) as varchar)+':15'
        else cast(DatePart(hour,startdatetime) as varchar)+':00'
        End
        as IntervalQuarterHour
from Contactcalldetail ccd
```

Comment: I was excited for a moment then saw "DatePart" which doesn't work with Informix :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to shamim reza for giving me a couple ideas on the logic:

```
  TO_CHAR(startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR, '%H')||':00' AS IntervalHour,
  Case when startdatetime::datetime minute to minute::char(2)::int >=30 then TO_CHAR(startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR, '%H')||':30'
     else TO_CHAR(startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR, '%H')||':00' 
  End as IntervalHalfHour,

  Case when startdatetime::datetime minute to minute::char(2)::int >=45 then TO_CHAR(startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR, '%H')||':45'
     when startdatetime::datetime minute to minute::char(2)::int >=30 then TO_CHAR(startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR, '%H')||':30'
     when startdatetime::datetime minute to minute::char(2)::int >=15 then TO_CHAR(startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR, '%H')||':15'
     else TO_CHAR(startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR, '%H')||':00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the torturous CASE statements shown in the other answers will obviously work, it's not the only solution. Even if you stick with it, encapsulating this logic inside a FUNCTION (SPL) would make the code much more reusable if it's going to appear in lots of code.

But I would suggest that set theory is what databases do best, and there's a better approach:

Create a table with all the ranges you require - this will be completely static, and if quarter-hour is the finest grain you need, you'll have 24 * 4 = 96 rows. It would look like this:

```
from_intvl | to_intvl | intvl_qtr | intvl_hlf | intvl_hr
-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------
00:00:00   | 00:14:59 | 00:00     | 00:00     | 0
00:15:00   | 00:29:59 | 00:15     | 00:00     | 0
...
08:30:00   | 08:44:59 | 08:30     | 08:30     | 8
...
22:45:00   | 22:59:59 | 22:45     | 22:30     | 22
...
```

The first two columns in that table are `DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND`, and the rest can be `DATETIME` of the appropriate granularity, or CHAR, INT or whatever suits your application.

Using it is as simple as:

```
SELECT ccd.startdatetime, it.intvl_qtr, it.intvl_hlf, it.intvl_hr
  FROM contactcalldetail AS ccd 
  JOIN intvl AS it 
    ON ccd.startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND BETWEEN it.from_intvl AND it.to_intvl
```

If you later decide you need 5 minute ranges, or 20 minute ranges, or even 4 hour blocks, it's trivial to add either more rows or more columns to your lookup table. Even going down to individual minute records would still only produce a table with 1,440 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a stored procedure to do the job.  While it could be done in an expression with enough casting, it would be unpleasant.  The key trick is converting the number of minutes past the hour into a `CHAR(2)` string, which is then auto-convertible to a number.  AFAIK, there isn't another way to convert an interval to a number.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Multiple_Of_Quarter_Hour;

CREATE PROCEDURE Multiple_Of_Quarter_Hour(dtval DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE
                                             DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO MINUTE)
    RETURNING DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE AS rounded_value;

    DEFINE mm CHAR(2);

    LET mm = EXTEND(dtval, MINUTE TO MINUTE);
    LET dtval = dtval - mm UNITS MINUTE;
    RETURN dtval + (15 * (mm / 15)::INTEGER) UNITS MINUTE;

END PROCEDURE;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Multiple_Of_N_Minutes;

CREATE PROCEDURE Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE
                                             DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO MINUTE,
                                       n_min INTEGER DEFAULT 15)
    RETURNING DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE AS rounded_value;

    DEFINE mm CHAR(2);

    LET mm = EXTEND(dtval, MINUTE TO MINUTE);
    LET dtval = dtval - mm UNITS MINUTE;
    RETURN dtval + (n_min * (mm / n_min)::INTEGER) UNITS MINUTE;

END PROCEDURE;
```

Test code:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t_times (dtval DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:04:59');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:06:59');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:14:59');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:15:00');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:16:57');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:21:00');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:24:36');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:25:11');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:29:59');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:30:00');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:35:44');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:44:59');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:45:00');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:49:53');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:50:30');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 00:59:59');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 01:16:07');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 01:34:10');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 02:24:46');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 04:32:08');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 11:52:09');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 14:00:28');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 16:10:31');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 17:46:58');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 19:25:35');
INSERT INTO t_times VALUES('2016-05-27 22:52:48');

SELECT dtval,
       Multiple_Of_Quarter_Hour(dtval) AS m15a,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval,  2), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m02,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval,  3), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m03,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval,  4), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m04,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval,  5), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m05,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval,  6), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m06
  FROM t_times
 ORDER BY dtval;

SELECT dtval,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 10), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m10,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 12), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m12,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 15), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m15b,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 20), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m20,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 30), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m30,
       EXTEND(Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval),     HOUR TO MINUTE) AS m15c
  FROM t_times
 ORDER BY dtval;
```

Sample outputs:

```
dtval                 m15a               m02     m03     m04     m05     m06
2016-05-27 00:00:00   2016-05-27 00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
2016-05-27 00:04:59   2016-05-27 00:00   00:04   00:03   00:04   00:00   00:00
2016-05-27 00:06:59   2016-05-27 00:00   00:06   00:06   00:04   00:05   00:06
2016-05-27 00:14:59   2016-05-27 00:00   00:14   00:12   00:12   00:10   00:12
2016-05-27 00:15:00   2016-05-27 00:15   00:14   00:15   00:12   00:15   00:12
2016-05-27 00:16:57   2016-05-27 00:15   00:16   00:15   00:16   00:15   00:12
2016-05-27 00:21:00   2016-05-27 00:15   00:20   00:21   00:20   00:20   00:18
2016-05-27 00:24:36   2016-05-27 00:15   00:24   00:24   00:24   00:20   00:24
2016-05-27 00:25:11   2016-05-27 00:15   00:24   00:24   00:24   00:25   00:24
2016-05-27 00:29:59   2016-05-27 00:15   00:28   00:27   00:28   00:25   00:24
2016-05-27 00:30:00   2016-05-27 00:30   00:30   00:30   00:28   00:30   00:30
2016-05-27 00:35:44   2016-05-27 00:30   00:34   00:33   00:32   00:35   00:30
2016-05-27 00:44:59   2016-05-27 00:30   00:44   00:42   00:44   00:40   00:42
2016-05-27 00:45:00   2016-05-27 00:45   00:44   00:45   00:44   00:45   00:42
2016-05-27 00:49:53   2016-05-27 00:45   00:48   00:48   00:48   00:45   00:48
2016-05-27 00:50:30   2016-05-27 00:45   00:50   00:48   00:48   00:50   00:48
2016-05-27 00:59:59   2016-05-27 00:45   00:58   00:57   00:56   00:55   00:54
2016-05-27 01:16:07   2016-05-27 01:15   01:16   01:15   01:16   01:15   01:12
2016-05-27 01:34:10   2016-05-27 01:30   01:34   01:33   01:32   01:30   01:30
2016-05-27 02:24:46   2016-05-27 02:15   02:24   02:24   02:24   02:20   02:24
2016-05-27 04:32:08   2016-05-27 04:30   04:32   04:30   04:32   04:30   04:30
2016-05-27 11:52:09   2016-05-27 11:45   11:52   11:51   11:52   11:50   11:48
2016-05-27 14:00:28   2016-05-27 14:00   14:00   14:00   14:00   14:00   14:00
2016-05-27 16:10:31   2016-05-27 16:00   16:10   16:09   16:08   16:10   16:06
2016-05-27 17:46:58   2016-05-27 17:45   17:46   17:45   17:44   17:45   17:42
2016-05-27 19:25:35   2016-05-27 19:15   19:24   19:24   19:24   19:25   19:24
2016-05-27 22:52:48   2016-05-27 22:45   22:52   22:51   22:52   22:50   22:48

dtval                 m10     m12     m15b    m20     m30     m15c
2016-05-27 00:00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
2016-05-27 00:04:59   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
2016-05-27 00:06:59   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
2016-05-27 00:14:59   00:10   00:12   00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
2016-05-27 00:15:00   00:10   00:12   00:15   00:00   00:00   00:15
2016-05-27 00:16:57   00:10   00:12   00:15   00:00   00:00   00:15
2016-05-27 00:21:00   00:20   00:12   00:15   00:20   00:00   00:15
2016-05-27 00:24:36   00:20   00:24   00:15   00:20   00:00   00:15
2016-05-27 00:25:11   00:20   00:24   00:15   00:20   00:00   00:15
2016-05-27 00:29:59   00:20   00:24   00:15   00:20   00:00   00:15
2016-05-27 00:30:00   00:30   00:24   00:30   00:20   00:30   00:30
2016-05-27 00:35:44   00:30   00:24   00:30   00:20   00:30   00:30
2016-05-27 00:44:59   00:40   00:36   00:30   00:40   00:30   00:30
2016-05-27 00:45:00   00:40   00:36   00:45   00:40   00:30   00:45
2016-05-27 00:49:53   00:40   00:48   00:45   00:40   00:30   00:45
2016-05-27 00:50:30   00:50   00:48   00:45   00:40   00:30   00:45
2016-05-27 00:59:59   00:50   00:48   00:45   00:40   00:30   00:45
2016-05-27 01:16:07   01:10   01:12   01:15   01:00   01:00   01:15
2016-05-27 01:34:10   01:30   01:24   01:30   01:20   01:30   01:30
2016-05-27 02:24:46   02:20   02:24   02:15   02:20   02:00   02:15
2016-05-27 04:32:08   04:30   04:24   04:30   04:20   04:30   04:30
2016-05-27 11:52:09   11:50   11:48   11:45   11:40   11:30   11:45
2016-05-27 14:00:28   14:00   14:00   14:00   14:00   14:00   14:00
2016-05-27 16:10:31   16:10   16:00   16:00   16:00   16:00   16:00
2016-05-27 17:46:58   17:40   17:36   17:45   17:40   17:30   17:45
2016-05-27 19:25:35   19:20   19:24   19:15   19:20   19:00   19:15
2016-05-27 22:52:48   22:50   22:48   22:45   22:40   22:30   22:45
```

Obviously, `Multiple_Of_Quarter_Hour()` could be written as a simple cover for `Multiple_Of_N_Minutes()`.

Single expression:

```
SELECT dtval,
       (EXTEND(dtval, YEAR TO MINUTE) -
           (EXTEND(dtval, MINUTE TO MINUTE)::CHAR(2)) UNITS MINUTE) +
           (15 * ((EXTEND(dtval, MINUTE TO MINUTE)::CHAR(2)) / 15)::INTEGER) UNITS MINUTE
  FROM t_times
 ORDER BY dtval;
```

If you have to write that more than once, it would be ludicrous not to use a stored procedure.

It is also possible, though a bit trickier, to round to the nearest multiple of N minutes instead of always truncating (so, for example, if the interval was 10 minutes, times from 13:55:00 to 14:04:59 would all be converted to 14:00).

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Nearest_Multiple_Of_N_Minutes;

CREATE PROCEDURE Nearest_Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
                                                     DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND,
                                               n_min INTEGER DEFAULT 15)
    RETURNING DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE AS rounded_value;

    DEFINE mm CHAR(2);
    DEFINE dt_yy_mm DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE;

    LET dt_yy_mm = dtval + ((30 * n_min) UNITS SECOND);
    LET mm = EXTEND(dt_yy_mm, MINUTE TO MINUTE);
    LET dt_yy_mm = dt_yy_mm - mm UNITS MINUTE;
    RETURN dt_yy_mm + (n_min * (mm / n_min)::INTEGER) UNITS MINUTE;

END PROCEDURE;

SELECT dtval,
       Nearest_Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 10) AS m10,
       Nearest_Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 15) AS m15,
       Nearest_Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 20) AS m20,
       Nearest_Multiple_Of_N_Minutes(dtval, 30) AS m30
  FROM t_times
 ORDER BY dtval;
```

Note the change of type of the time argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it.

```
SELECT
    startdatetime,
    IntervalHour,
    IntervalHour + (minutes/30)::INT * 30 UNITS MINUTE,
    IntervalHour + (minutes/15)::INT * 15 UNITS MINUTE
FROM (
    SELECT
            startdatetime,
            EXTEND(TRUNC(startdatetime, 'HH'), HOUR TO MINUTE) AS IntervalHour,
            TO_CHAR(startdatetime, '%M') AS minutes
    FROM contactcalldetail
)
```

Basically you get the `IntervalHour` by using the [TRUNC](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1481.htm) function to truncate the date to the beginning of the hour. And use the [EXTEND](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1540.htm) function to adjust the precision of the `DATETIME`.

> **Do not use the** [ROUND](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1480.htm) function, because it will round the date to the beginning of the nearest hour or minute.

Extract the minutes using the [TO_CHAR](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1542.htm) function and use simple math with the [UNITS operator](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1460.htm) to get the lower interval, no need for [CASE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1442.htm).